# Confusion over subspace dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ where $W$ is the set of all $5$-tuples that satisfy the following conditions:
$$2x_1-x_2+\frac{4}{3}x_3-x_4+0x_5=0$$$$x_1+0x_2+\frac{2}{3}x_3+0x_4-x_5=0$$$$9x_1-3x_2+6x_3-3x_4-3x_5=0$$
and I am tasked with finding a finite set of vectors that spans $W$.

After putting the coefficients of the 3 linear combinations into a matrix and applying RREF I get the following row reduced system:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&\frac{2}{3}&0&-1\\0&1&0&1&-2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
With three variables here, I can choose arbitrary parameters for $x_i, i=3,4,5$, so I select $r, s, t$.  Thus
$$x_1=\frac{-2}{3}r+t, x_2=-s+2t, x_3=r, x_4=s, x_5=t$$

So for my question.  Since the conditions on $W$ give a homogeneous system, in effect, the conditions are providing a nullspace for a particular transformation and thus, by the rank nullity theorem, since the rank is 2 (from the RREF matrix of coefficients), the nullspace is dimension 3, does this mean that the a finite set of vectors should be a set of 3 vectors?  in essence, I can set $r=1, s=t=0$ as the first vector, $r=t=0, s=1$ as the second, and $r=s=0, t=1$ as the third and this will provide my set?

Comment: Should be good.  I haven't checked your working, but your ideas are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you can write the (reduced) system $Ax = 0$ as
$I \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} {2 \over 3} & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{bmatrix} $, or in other words,
$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = -
\begin{bmatrix} {2 \over 3} & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{bmatrix} $.

That is, you can pick $x_3,x_4,x_5$ arbitrarily, and $x_1,x_2$ will be given by the expression above.

Now choose **any** basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the one you choose above, $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is a suitable one), assign
$\begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{bmatrix} $ to each one and compute the corresponding $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$. The resulting three vectors will span the null space.